# How to get the response code from Firestore Task

Tags: android, exception, google-cloud-firestore

In the `com.google.android.gms.tasks` I want to know what types of Exception there are and how to filter them on error response?

This demonstrates what I'd like to see:

```
   db.collection("users")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                         for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                             s(document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                         }
                     } else {
// Demonstrating here what I like to see using the okhttp respons code as en example.. 
                         switch (task.getException().getCause()) {// obviously not working only for demonstration.. 
                            case "OK":
                               return Status.OK;
                            case "ZERO_RESULTS":
                               return Status.ZERO_RESULTS;
                            case "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":
                               return Status.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT;
                            case "REQUEST_DENIED":
                               return Status.REQUEST_DENIED;
                            case "INVALID_REQUEST":
                               return Status.INVALID_REQUEST;
                            default:
                               return null;
                         }
                     }
                 }
             });
```

It would be great if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this myself, but from going over the reference documentation you should be able to call [`FirebaseFirestoreException.getCode()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code):

```
((FirebaseFirestoreException)task.getException()).getCode()
```

This gives you one of the codes documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code

Comment: wow your the King! ,  I missed that Thanks and for quick response